# How to bulk change processing WooCommerce orders from a specific date using SQL?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to bulk change ~1000 older orders that are still marked as "processing". Another answer described this line of SQL:

```
update wp_posts set post_status = 'wc-completed' where post_type = 'shop_order' and post_status ='wc-processing' ;
```

How can I modify the command so that it only changes orders older than 1 year?

Answer (score 0):

For That you can use `INTERVAL`

```
update wp_posts set post_status = 'wc-completed' 
where post_type = 'shop_order' and post_status ='wc-processing' 
AND post_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR AND NOW();
```